# jquery selector specification, No ID or class

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I want to change text "en-us" to "en-gb"(and lot another options, but that is not my question)

```
<tr>
  <td>
  <td > <span>
   <div>
    <div>
     <div>
      <div> 
        <span >en-us</span> ; </div>
     </div>
    </div>
 </div>
</span> </span>
</td>
</tr>
```

I can not catch ID or specific class, so I need help with selection in jQuery selector. This was my idea, but it is not working:

```
    $('tr td:nth-child(2) span span div div div span').val("en-gb");
```

Could you get me working solution? http://jsfiddle.net/n6354/

Comment: A div inside a span is not valid, so the browser probably tries to fix that and the markup ends up being completely different from what you think. Write valid HTML and it's probably easier.

Comment: Moreover, your closing and opening tags are unbalanced.

Comment: @adeneo: Which is to say, the DOM ends up not being what the markup looks like it would be... (The *markup* is unchanged.)

Comment: sorry for poor code, corect one is here http://jsfiddle.net/n6354/ I have just take it from original code and improve it for readability

Comment: @JakubClosed: To improve a question, use the "edit" link on the question, not comments.

Comment: @A.Wolff: The ending `</td>` is one of the tags that can legally be omitted: http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#optional-tags Good idea? No. But legal.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Ya, i was just checking that. I remember you already told me about that ;) Thx TJ!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See here:

http://jsfiddle.net/n6354/2/

```
.html("en-gb");
```

This works fine.
Use the html() not the val()
This is not input

Comment: nice it works, thanks. I have been using .val somwhere else and did not think about it.

Answer (score 0):

What about using the :contains() selector?

```
$("span:contains('en-us')").text('en-gb');
```

Reference: http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 $('tr td:nth-child(2) div span').html('en-gb');
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/n6354/4/)**